# What is the scope of the utm_campaign dimension in Google Analytics v4 on Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm using Google Analytics v4 in my Android app and I want to use the [Campaign Measurements](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns) to see where my users are coming from.

The app is currently under development so it's not available in Google Play, but I'm planning to distribute some preview builds by sending out the apk file directly before I make the first release on Google Play.

I still want to be able to do campaign tracking on these builds so I'm planning to send [hard-coded campaign data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns) using [`setCampaignParamsFromUrl()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.HitBuilder.html#setCampaignParamsFromUrl(java.lang.String)) instead of listening to the `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent.

The question is, how often do I need to include the campaign data in my hits to Google Analytics? For every hit, once every session, or only once when they change?

For custom dimensions you can specify a [scope](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#scope) for your dimensions, but what are the scope for the campaign related dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the campaign data only with the first screen view hit. Analytics should associate the campaign with the app instance cid and attribute further data to it.

INSTALL_REFERRER intent work in a similar way. The campaign data is received from INSTALL_REFERRER intent when app first launches and the campaign params are attached to the next hit.

Comment: Does this also mean that I can only include campaign data on the first screen view hit? I'm trying to send campaign data, but I don't see it in the web interface (two days after I sent the hits). I assume this is because I have already sent hits for my user without campaign data so my app id is now permanently associated with the data I send with the first hit (no campaign data). Is this correct?

Comment: Even with a new user that sends this data with the first hit I send I still don't see my campaign data. But that's a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932236/how-can-i-set-campaign-with-google-analytics-using-setcampaignparamsfromurl

Comment: I believe that you can send campaign data with any hit. Google Analytics should attribute any further hits to the provided campaign.