# How can I set campaign with Google Analytics using setCampaignParamsFromUrl()

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

**Update**

This was caused by a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=596) that Google have fixed in "Release Version 4.5 - Google Play Services 7.3 (May 1, 2015)". When using Google Play Services 7.3 or later it should be possible to call `setCampaignParametersFromUrl()` with a full URL as expected.

---

**Original question**

I'm using Google Analytics V4 in my Android app. On startup I send a screen view hit to Google Analytics and I set the campaign parameters on my [HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder.html) by calling [`setCampaignParamsFromUrl()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.HitBuilder.html#setCampaignParamsFromUrl(java.lang.String)) like this:

```
String url = "http://example.com/?referrer=utm_source%3Down-build%26utm_campaign%3Dinternal-testing";
builder.setCampaignParamsFromUrl(url);
```

It seems like this is working because I can see that the campaign is included in the logs from Google Analytics:

```
V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service ...,  cn=internal-testing...
```

However when I'm looking at my data at the Google Analytics web interface the next day this campaign does not show up. I only have users with campaign "(not set)".

I've uninstalled my app, cleared the advertising id and re-installed the app and I see this installation as a new user in the Google Analytics web interface so I know the data is sent there. But the campaign I use does not show up.

Am I using `setCampaignParamsFromUrl()` wrongly or have I missed something else? Do I have to configure the campaigns I have somewhere or should Google Analytics pick up values it hasn't seen before as new campaigns automatically?

(As for why I'm not listening to the install referrer event see: [What is the scope of the utm_campaign dimension in Google Analytics v4 on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874399/what-is-the-scope-of-the-utm-campaign-dimension-in-google-analytics-v4-on-androi/28883267#28883267))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: [issue 596](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=596) have been fixed by Google, it is now possible to call `setCampaignParamsFromUrl()` with a URL when using the latest version of Google Play Services (7.3 released May 1st 2015)**

After some testing I managed to figure out what is going on and exactly what format the URL passed to [`setCampaignParamsFromUrl()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.HitBuilder.html#setCampaignParamsFromUrl(java.lang.String)) should have.

**TL;DR: Generate an URL using the [Google Play URL Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder), but pass only the referrer string (part after `referrer=`) to `setCampaignParamsFromUrl()`.**

When `setCampaignParamsFromUrl()` is called it starts by taking everything after the '?' and splitting it on each '&' to get a list of all parameters it should send to GA.

For each parameter it then splits on '=' and takes the first substring as parameter and the second as value for that parameter.

Normally this works good, but it does not work for URLs generated by the Google Play URL builder. After un-escaping the parameter string of the URL used in the original question we get the string:

```
referrer=utm_source=own-build&utm_campaign=internal-testing
```

After splitting on '&' we get the following two strings

```
1. referrer=utm_source=own-build
2. utm_campaign=internal-testing
```

The second can be handled nicely where `utm_campaign` gets assigned the value "internal-testing", but the first is problematic. There we get the parameter `referrer` with the value "utm_source". Since `referrer` is not a valid campaign parameter it is not reported to GA, and since utm_source is a required parameter GA will treat this campaign data as invalid and ignore all the other parameters reported at the same time.

So to get `setCampaignParamsFromUrl()` to work you can pass in only the referrer string, that is everything after `referrer=` in the URL generated by the Google Play URL Builder. So the URL used in the original question should be

```
utm_source%3Down-build%26utm_campaign%3Dinternal-testing
```

The package name that is part of the URL generated by the URL builder is not needed at all since the GA SDK picks up the package automatically.

Since this behavior feels like a bug to me this has been reported as [issue 596](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=596) in the GA bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Try building your URL with the form provided at the end of the Campaigns dev guide:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Also, make sure you don't have sampling enabled. If you are testing this from a single device/emulator and you have sampling enabled your campaign data might be ignored.

Comment: I've tried to build an URL with the form provided, but that didn't help. Since I don't have my app in the play store I just entered a fake package name. I have now tried to change the package name in the url to my apps package name in case that is required. But now I have to wait until tomorrow until the data shows up in GA so debugging this is really slow. I've also made sure sampling is disabled and when I launch the app I can see that data is reported in the live view.

Comment: Google Analytics allows multiple apps to be tracked with the same tracker id. The app package is important. I believe you must use the actual package name of campaign attribution to correctly work.

Comment: I changed to the actual package name but that didn't help. Then I did a couple of other changes as well and then I started to see data in Google Analytics. I will continue to experiment over the coming days to try to figure out what it was that I were missing.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Using the Google Play URL Builder is actually what makes setCampaignParamsFromUrl() not work. See my own answer for more details.